# Use of the word "Buffet"

Tags: meaning

My friend and I were both arguing over this. I always thought a buffet referred to **style** of a restaurant in which food was mass produced and served in large containers, not necessarily having to be "all you can eat". My friend thought that the word buffet itself means all you can eat. So which one of us right?

Comment: You are correct.  When you can eat as much as you want, it's called an "all you can eat buffet."  But "all-you-can-eat" is not limited to buffets, many sushi restaurants sell all-you-can-eat sushi, but you don't serve yourself as one does at a buffet.  Buffet, by every dictionary definition I can find, simply means that the person eating serves themselves.

Comment: You're both correct.  And both wrong.  Depends on whose definitions you use, and definitions vary by locality and culture.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime is correct, as well as you.. HOWEVER, buffets are so commonly "all you can eat" especially for breakfasts and brunches or salad bar buffets,  that I do think the presumption in those cases is that you can go back for more.  I think the basic meaning of the word is drifting towards presuming "all you can eat" without qualification.

Comment: This is all referring to the noun _buffet_, pronounced /bə'fe/; there is also a noun _buffet_ 'a blow, typically of the hand or fist', and a corresponding verb, but they're both pronounced /'bəfət/.

Comment: So if I buy a [buffet table](https://www.crateandbarrel.com/steppe-buffet-table/s668581) to keep at home does Crate&Barrel have to feed me for life?

Comment: There is the cross-Channel ferry which announced bilingually *"Ladies and gentleman, the buffet is now open. Mesdames et messieurs, le snack-bar est maintenant ouvert"*.  You would have been expected to pay

Comment: Also the food-service carriage on a (British) train is referred to as the *buffet*, despite being a counter-service arrangement (i.e. you order from and pay a person standing the other side of the counter). The word is also used for station cafes, even in some cases when they're table-service.

Comment: @ChrisH - Yeah, I can recall a few US "diners" or "cafes" over the years who referred to themselves as "buffets".   But that sense is becoming less popular (as are the diners and cafes).

Comment: @ChrisH Spot on! British Railways/British Rail of yore hijacked the word and it became synonymous with curled up sandwiches, dodgy sausage rolls  and, if you were lucky, surprisingly good cooked breakfasts (bacon&eggs, etc.) on mainline inter-city trains till the mid-1970's. The station buffet was a mood-inducing scene in British B&W movies throughout the 1940's and 50's. Think Brief Encounter & Witness for the Prosecution. Ah, those were the days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Buffet" is not defined as all you can eat.  That is merely a possible "side effect".

The basic definition, common to all dictionaries I checked, is that it is a serve-yourself format.  Various dictionaries add additional characteristics to the definition, such as:

- It includes a number of dishes (typically the case) [*Oxford*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buffet)
- It is served on a long table (possible if there are a lot of items, but nothing restricts the shape, number, or arrangement of serving tables). [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/buffet)
- It consists of cold foods (I've never heard of that restricted usage) [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/buffet)

Implied by the serve-yourself definition:

- At least for the items in the buffet, you don't give an order to a server for what you want and they bring it to you.
- It is a fixed price rather than an item-based price.

The fact that you serve yourself implies that there may not be restrictions on how much you serve yourself, in which case that would effectively make it an all-you-can-eat situation.  But a restaurant could put restrictions on it (access to plates and utensils, limit on number of helpings, a posted request that you limit servings, etc.).  Such restrictions would not violate the definition of a buffet.  So a buffet is not necessarily all-you-can eat.